# Joint pdf of sum and difference of (0,1) normal RV

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

I need to find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ where $X=Z_1+Z_2$ and $Y=Z_1-Z_2$. And $Z_1,Z_2$ are indepent and standard normally distributed.

I've proved that $X$ and $Y$ are both normally distributed with mean $0$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{2}$. I've also proved that the covariance is $0$, but I am not sure how that helps. I don't require a proof just some ideas that I might be missing so I can continue.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the change of variables formula helps (see here for instance for an example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346416/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $E e^{tX+sY}=Ee^{(t+s)Z_1+(t-s)Z_2)}=Ee^{(t+s)Z_1}Ee^{(t-s)Z_2)}=e^{(t+s)^{2}/2}e^{(t-s)^{2}/2}$. Simplify this to get $e^{t^{2}}e^{s^{2}}$ and conclude that $X,Y$ are actually independent and that they have a joint normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you! In the final part, the moment generating is the same as the product of the moment generating of two normal distributions, therefore they are independt...? I only knew the theorem to go from moment generating to distributions in 1D

Comment: Yes, if the joint MGF is the product of the marginal MGF's then the random variables are independent. @GEW6